# Emoji font in Ruby on Rails 6 app don't work when loaded locally from assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firefox, fonts, asset-pipeline

In my Ruby on Rails 6 Apple Color Emojis don't work on Firefox(macOS&windows10).

[image]

I had imported the font:

```
@import url(//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/5ab304ade0d4f62d027d12464ca69443?family=Apple+Color+Emoji);
```

and they started to work!

[image]

Now I want to have them locally in my app.

I found on google that it is a common issue and there is even a nice solution to fix that [solution by Nick Galbreath](https://www.client9.com/css-color-emoji-stack/).

```
// define a new font face that just deals with emoji
@font-face {
font-family: "color-emoji";
src: local("Apple Color Emoji"),
     local("Segoe UI Emoji"), 
     local("Segoe UI Symbol"),
     local("Noto Color Emoji"); }

// add it *after* the serif, sans-serif or monospace
// ending default.
body {
  font-family: your-font, sans-serif, color-emoji;
}
```

So I prepared @font-face for first font "Apple Color Emojis" like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AppleColorEmoji';
  src: asset-url('color-emoji/AppleColorEmoji/AppleColorEmoji.eot');
  src: asset-url('color-emoji/AppleColorEmoji/AppleColorEmoji.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  asset-url('color-emoji/AppleColorEmoji/AppleColorEmoji.woff') format('woff'),
  asset-url('color-emoji/AppleColorEmoji/AppleColorEmoji.woff2') format('woff2'),
  asset-url('color-emoji/AppleColorEmoji/AppleColorEmoji.ttf') format('truetype'),
  asset-url('color-emoji/AppleColorEmoji/AppleColorEmoji.svg#Apple Color Emoji') format('svg');
}
```

Files are in **app/assets/fonts/color-emoji/AppleColorEmoji** and when I try to use my brand new @font-face like **font-family: 'AppleColorEmoji';** guess what happen?

Yes, they don't work.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I got such error in a console:

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: 
"AppleColorEmoji" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) 
source: http://localhost:3000/assets/color- 
emoji/AppleColorEmoji/AppleColorEmoji- 
3ec445c87ae85d4ae8c4fdc2e7f5dfbe85e755b057c254af9e0f36a7cc6924e2.eot
```

Comment: can you check the fonts under network tab, and see if the font is loaded? Also try to use `font-url`, instead of the general one `asset-url`

Comment: Yes, it is loaded. Nothing happens when I used `font-url` instead. + I just edited my post with an error which I got from firefox console.

Comment: Yeez. Font-face looks like this `@font-face { font-family: 'AppleColorEmoji' }`. So I tried to use it in my CSS like `font-family: 'AppleColorEmoji';`. I changed it to `font-family: 'Apple Color Emocji';` and now it works.